# Bokeh plot not stretching to fill remaining space

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to stretch out the middle plot inside the bokeh tab.
The middle figure is constructed as:

```
p = figure(tools=['xpan', 'reset', 'save','xwheel_zoom'],x_axis_type='datetime', plot_height=650, plot_width=950,
            toolbar_location='left', title= "Monthly cashflows roll out")

l = layout([
        [column([inputs, pie]), p, column(cardsVarColumn,cardsStatColumn)]
    ])
```

I tried adding `sizing_mode='stretch_both'`
But the middle plot still doesnt strethc out to fill the remaining space as seen on the picture:

[image]

Comment: Please aways include version information. Layout in particular has undergone several iterations over the last few years. It is not possible to say anything meaningful at all without knowing what version this is in reference to.

Comment: bokeh ver 1.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the sizing_mode stretch_both to the column with the plot that you would like to stretch to fill the remaining space.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models.widgets import Select, RangeSlider, PreText
from bokeh.layouts import column, row

p1 = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
p1.circle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], size=20, color="navy", alpha=0.5)

p2 = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
p2.square([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], size=20, color="olive", alpha=0.5)

select1 = Select(title="Select Variable:", value="Linear equal principal", options=["Linear equal principal", "foo", "bar"])
select2 = Select(title="Currency:", value="EUR", options=["EUR", "USD"])
range_slider = RangeSlider(start=0, end=10, value=(1,9), step=.1, title="Date Range")

pre1 = PreText(text="Total interests CF in a date range", width=300, height=50)
pre2 = PreText(text="Outstanding Principal", width=300, height=50)
pre3 = PreText(text="Number of Loans", width=300, height=50)

show(row(column(select1, select2, range_slider, p1), column(children=[p2], sizing_mode='stretch_both'), column(pre1, pre2, pre3)))
```

[image]

Comment: so in my case should i put `p` plot into column and then use sizing_mode or should i apply the sizing mode directly somehow?

Comment: You should put plot p into a column and set sizing_mode to stretch_both for the column.

Comment: I tried doing that however it seems to not change anything in the plot: `l = layout([
        [column([inputs, pie]), column(p, sizing_mode='stretch_both'), column(cardsVarColumn,cardsStatColumn)]
    ])`

Comment: Could you add the complete script and some example data to your question so I can try it with your code?